# getting access denied to user on my laravel project hosted on cpanel

Tags: sql, laravel, environment-variables, cpanel

so i have been trying to get a laravel project of mine working on cpanel web host and i keep getting access denied to the user, i have cross checked my database name and user on the .env file no luck

```
APP_NAME=#####
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:IGN5qlcuICOZ3LAeIMPh+DXtTPA/51P2tCIRW1DmDY4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=####

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

I get a laravel error, access denied to dbuser can not (select * from projects)

Comment: We have no way of helping you without logs, or at least knowing who the cPanel hosting provider is.

Comment: Have you migrate your database on server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you see your environment file?
2. Did you already enable viewing of hidden files?

If your answer to question 2 is no and you are seeing the file, then your environment file is most likely saved as "env" not ".env", check it and change it accordingly.

To enable viewing of hidden files,

In the file manager in cpanel, click on the settings at the top-right corner then you would see "show hidden files", tick the checkbox.

Also ensure your php version on the server matches the version in your developement environment.

To do this, on your local environment type "php -v" to see the version.

On the server, type "php" on your cpanel home search and click on "php select version". Set it to the exact version you have on your local development environment.